# Bertsimas & Tsitsiklis's Linear Optimization book

Tags: linear-programming, book-recommendation, advice

I just want to ask a question about the "level" of this book. In the book's preface it is written that the only prerequisite is knowledge of Linear Algebra.

Is this book good for undergraduate student with knowledge of Linear Algebra, single and multivariable Calculus? Or do I need something less intensive?

Answer (score 1):

The book is one of the more mathematically rigorous stuff on this subject at undergraduate level, and the problems are quite challenging at times. However, given your background it should be more than enough!
Another good reference is Karloff but I'd say Bertsimas would be better.